# Call remoteForm to update only one div with onChange event

Tags: ajax, function, grails, submit, gsp

I want to update `div` contents upon entering data in a `textField` dynamically.
I have tried the following:

```
<g:formRemote name="changeText" on404="alert('not found!')" update="resultDiv"
    url="[ controller: 'results', action:'results' ]">
        <g:textField onChange="submit();" name="text"/>
</g:formRemote>
```

Everything work except a new page is render and the `div` is not updated...

```
def results = {
   render "new content"
}
```

Comment: can you post your results action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following GSP code:

```
<g:formRemote name="changeText" on404="alert('not found!')" update="resultDiv"
          url="[ controller: 'results', action:'results' ]">
```

Will generate a new HTML form with an `onSubmit` method like that:

```
<form id="form_id" action="/action" method="post" onsubmit="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:jQuery(this).serialize(), url:'/action',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#resultDiv').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false">
```

So the Javascript code that will trigger the AJAX call is on the `onSubmit()` method.

The problem here is that you are calling `submit()` action using Javascript and this doesn't trigger the `onSubmit()` method.

A solution would be to call the `onSubmit()` method directly in the `onChange` event:

```
<g:textField onChange="this.form_id.onsubmit();" name="text"/>
```

Comment: Or you can even remove the event : `<g:textField name="text"/>`

Answer (score 1):

`Grails` provides an awesome tag for this: [remoteField](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteField.html)

```
<g:remoteField name="input" controller="results" action="results" onSuccess="jQuery('#resultDiv').html(data)"/>

<div id="resultDiv"></div>
```